# Using jQuery to set checkbox property inside a repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi all this is a simple and stupid one as I'm not smart enough to figure it out. So I have the following ordered list inside an `asp:Repeater` --

```
<ul id="KeyAreaUl">
   <asp:Repeater ID="Rptr" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
         <li runat="server" id="ActiveLiElement" class='<%# IsActive(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Key").ToString())%>'>
            <asp:CheckBox Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Key")%>' runat="server" ID="KeyCheckbox" Checked="false" />
            <a href="#"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Key") %></a>
         </li>
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

I'm adding/removing class `active` to the `li` element from code behind based on current `querystring`. The goal is to write a jQuery script that sets the `Checkbox` property to `Checked` if the corresponding `li` has class `active`.

My attempt (an unsuccessful one) was --

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('#KeyAreaUl li').hasClass('active')) {
          $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);               
        };
     });
</script>
```

The Problem I'm facing is, the script sets all the checkboxes as checked if a `li` element has `active` class. Whereas the goal is to set the checkbox checked only when its parent `li` has class `active`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work in your case :

```
$('#KeyAreaUl li').each(function(){ 
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);               
    }; 
})
```

Comment: Might? It actually works... just tested.  Many thanks

Comment: @envyM6 never sure what could happen :)) thanks for the feedback !